# Richfaces panel styles suddenly wont load

Tags: richfaces, styles

This is really frustrating ...

Suddenly the richfaces panel styles have just stopped loading.

The generated css links:

```
<link rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css' href='/MCSA-web/a4j_3_1_4.GAcss/panel.xcss/DATB/eAFTL4ziAQACswD..mcsa' />
<link rel='stylesheet'  type='text/css' href='/MCSA-web/a4j_3_1_4.GAcss/table.xcss/DATB/eAFTL4ziAQACswD..mcsa' />
```

The styles from the 'table.xcss' style load correctly. The styles from 'panel.xcss' portion do not load, when I try to expand these styles for viewing in firebug I get the message:

```
'Failed to load source for: http://host-test/MCSA-web/a4j_3_1_4.GAcss/panel.xcss/DATB/eAFTL4ziAQACswD..mcsa'
```

However, another JSF/Richfaces app I have running on the same server is still able to load these styles ... this other application uses the EXACT SAME web.xml and faces-config.xml files (I literally copy/pasted them).

I have tried:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>ALL</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but this does not solve the issue.

... I'm totally at a loss here, does anyone have any experience with this? Why is it just the panel styles that fail???

Also you might notice I'm using richfaces 3.14, can't get around this sadly so I'm stuck with that at the moment. I've seen various other questions on many sites where people have been having problems with richfaces styles loading (various versions of richfaces) but I've yet to find a solution that works.

:(

Comment: They just started loading again inexplicably after 5 hours of not working ...

I have no idea why, I didn't change anything >:|

If anyone still has any information about this it would still be appreciated as I'd like to be able to rely on this to not happen again.

Comment: annnnd now they're gone again, no changes besides to unrelated java code ... /wrists

Answer (score 1):

Ok well I found out the cause though I'm sort of unclear why it was happening only sometimes ...

Anyway, I'm using a PhaseListener to handle access/authorization, it looks like sometimes this would block a resource load request so I added the following check before the authorization checking code and it seems to always load now:

```
if (!event.getSource().getClass().equals(ResourceLifecycle.class))
```